# Updating Junction Table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, architecture, knex.js

I have two tables `product` and `tag` with a junction table `products_tags`. A product can have many different tags, and a tag can have many different products, but the relationship between one product and one tag needs to be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE tag (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE products_tags (
   product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES product(id),
   tag_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES tag(id),
   PRIMARY KEY(product_id, tag_id)
)
```

I am currently planning of updating the junction table by sending a `tags` array with the Product object every time it is updated by the frontend layer, delete all rows in `products_tags` that contain the current `product_id` and create a new row in `products_tags` for each ID in the `tags` array.

My question is: Is there a more efficient way of achieving this? Or is deleting and reinserting the rows the only sane way to guarantee data integrity in a junction table?

Comment: It will cause too many row versions to be created, even, when the changes are minimal(that could cost 2*N affected rows!). Better insert what is not in the DB table+ delete what is not in the new list ;

Comment: You are right @wildplasser I think I will create a postgres function to handle this, doing it in the application layer feels like it would cause too many roundtrips to the db and possibly get messy.

Comment: Function is not needed here.You could use a chained CTE to combine both operations. And maybe put it in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be struggling with this, this is what I ended up with. Probably still can be optimized but definitely a much better solution than the one in my initial question.

```
WITH insert_new_tags AS (
    INSERT INTO products_tags (product_id, tag_id)
        VALUES (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 7)
        ON CONFLICT (product_id, tag_id)
        DO NOTHING
    RETURNING *
),
delete_missing_tags AS (
    DELETE FROM products_tags
    WHERE product_id = 2 AND tag_id NOT IN (1, 2, 7)
    RETURNING *
)

SELECT *, 'inserted' AS operation FROM insert_new_tags
UNION
SELECT *, 'deleted' AS operation FROM delete_missing_tags
```

Big tnks to @wildplasser for pointing me in the right direction!